# How to conditionally update state based on previous state in react functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So, I want to do the following,

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({})
const updateName = (name)
setValue(previousState => {
  if (/*check some conditions*/) {
    // dont update the state
  } else {
    return { /* some new state */ }
  }
});
```

Is there anyway how can i achieve it?

Comment: Sure, just replace `// dont update the state` with `return previousState`

Comment: wont it update and re render the component

Comment: No, it will not rerender. When you set state in a function component, react does an `===` between the old state and the new state. If they're equal, it does not render.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are almost there.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({})

setValue((prevState) => {
  if (condition to not update) {
    return prevState;
  } else {
    return newState;
  }
});
```

You don't necessarily need to do it from the `setValue` call. You can also do it like this:

```
const updateSomething = () => {
  if (shouldUpdate)
    setValue(newState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something simple like:

```
setValue(!value)
```

That will just change a boolean state, passing from false value to true value and vice versa.

I hope it can help.

Comment: I think that will work, but the recommended way is using [functional update of state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), like `setValue(previousValue => !previousValue)`